# This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode. AntiForgeryToken

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

I'm running IIS7, .NET 4.5 and have a site that is MVC2.

I'm getting the error "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode." when I navigate to a page (an aspx View) with a form on it with an AntiForgeryToken on it.

```
<%=Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
```

I've searched around and seen the AddHeaders solution that fixes this error for other people (who are running IIS6) but I can't see how that would be similar.

The reason I mention the AntiForgeryToken, is because if I take that line out, the page works!

EDIT:
I've tried reinstalling .NET 4.5 - didn't help

EDIT: My AppPool is definitely set to "Integrated" Managed Pipeline Mode (ApplicationPoolIdentity). It's the only app in this app pool.

Comment: I know it's not an IIS6 issue, since that's what we're currently stuck on where I work. Is this on a view or on a `WebForms` page within the MVC project?

Comment: Also might be worth seeing if this key is your `system.webServer` section of the web.config: `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />`

Comment: This is happening on a View (aspx file). And yes I do have validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" - do you think that might be interfering somehow?

Comment: No - I have yet had a need to change that value, using MVC2 - 4.

Comment: Is your app pool running in integrated mode, and if not is there any reason why it can't be changed? You can check in IIS, under the application pools section.

Comment: I've edited the original post - sorry Toby, I should have said already - is definitely in Integrated mode already.

Answer (score 3):

Run the application in IIS Express. This solved the same issue to me. Just right click your project and choose "properties" and click "Web" tab, there under servers click "use localIIS web server and click "USE IIS express"

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to MVC3 using the upgrade tool has fixed the problem
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx?Redirected=true

I realise this isn't always a viable fix for everyone - so will leave this question open, hopefully someone else has an idea on fixing the MVC2 solution.